# A problem of decimals..

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

The exact problem:

For any natural number n>1, write the infinite decimal expansion of $\frac{1}{n}$ (for example, we write 1/2 = $0.4\overline9$ as it's infinite decimal expansion, not 0.5). Determine the length of the non periodic part of the (infinite) decimal expansion of $\frac{1}{n}$

I do not see how it is possible to do this in generality, I think that this may have something to do with primes, although I can't figure it out.. also if this is in generality then what about numbers like $\frac{1}{11}$? which do not have nice expansions? Help appreciated!

Comment: In general, geometric series tell us that repeating decimal expansions correspond to writing $\frac{1}{n}=\frac{m}{10^k-1}$ for some integers $m,k$. Consider how you could find such a $k$.

Comment: By the way, $0.5\overline0$ has the same length of non periodic part as $0.4\overline 9$.

Comment: @πr8 But won't $10^k-1$ always be odd? so what value of m,k would I have for 1/2?

Comment: @Nikunj That's true - when $n$ has factors of $2$ and $5$, you absorb them out (they end up corresponding to translating the decimal expansion), so it's most important to focus on $n$ coprime to $2$ and $5$. One justification of the $1/2$ expansion is to write it as $\frac{1}{10}\cdot \frac{45}{10-1}$ - note that extracting powers of $10$ will not change the period length.

Comment: I'd also point out .5 *is* infinite repeating.  It infinitely repeats 0.  Also If you are asked for the *none* repeating part then the non 2 and 5 multiples have have *no* non-repeating parts.  i.e. everything repeats.

Comment: @πr8 yes you're right, I see that powers of 10 will not effect the period length but I still don't see how we get a nice general expression in which we plug the value of n and we get the period length,.

Comment: Are you sure it is  to find the length of the *non* periodic part?  Finding the length of the periodic part is much more interesting.

Comment: @fleablood yes, it's the non-periodic part

Comment: experiments show that if $n=2^a5^bc$ with $c$ not divisible by $2$ and $5$ then the length is $max(a,b)$. I guess you'll find a proof by making the denominator to $10^k-1$

Comment: Nothing to do with primes and 1/11 = 0.0909090909... does have a very nice expansion.  It's 1/67 that has a nasty long one.

Comment: @fleablood you're right and I'll remove the prime tag~

Comment: Thinking it had something to do with primes was good instinct.  But in actuality it didn't.  These things happen.   Divisibility by 2 and 5 (i.e. relative primeness to 10) does matter so it does have a *little* bit to do with primes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to re-write this in a few hours.  The following is correct but I think I can explain it much cleaner, clearer and neater.  But... I have things to do right now.

New answer in a few hours.

======

Let's call that number $h(n)$.  $h(10^k*n) = h(n)+ k$.  We are dividing 1/n by $1/10^k$ which adds $k$ zeroes.

If $n = 2^j$ or $n= 5^j$ then the answer is $j$.  Because $n | 10^j$ but doesn't divide into any lower power of 10.

If neither $2$ nor $5$ divide into $n$ then $h(n) = 0$.  In finding the decimals you are taking remainders, multiplying them, and dividing by n.  There are only a finite number of remainders possible so eventually the string will repeat.  But when it does:  $10R = q*n + r$.  Not only is the next remainder forced, so is the previous remainder.  So the pattern can only repeat from the very begining.  (This isn't the case for $m/n$ the first remainder is m*10 = q*n + r; the first term being m rather than 1, puts an "artificial" beginning.)

The final case is $n = 2^km$ or $n = 5^km$; $m$ not divisible by 2 or 5.  In that the answer is $k$ .  This is because $1/n = 1/m*1/(2or5)^k$. $1/m$ will have no nonrepeating part and $1/(2or5)^k$ will have $k$ nonrepeating part.

==== Draft of new answer =====

Pre-script: *I'm not going to worry about converting a terminating decimal into a decimal with trailing 9s.  If the terminating decimal has* n *terms, the last term is non-zero.  Converting it to one with trailing 9s will result in* n *non-repeating terms.  This is exactly the same as the number of non-repeating terms had we left it as a terminating decimal.*

Let's refer to the number of non-repeating digits of $1/n$ as $h(n)$.

If $n = 2^j5^km$ then $h(n) = \max(j,k)$.

Case 1: Neither $2$ nor $5$ divides $n$.  Then $n = 2^05^0m$ and $h(n) = 0$.

Pf:

When we calculate the digital expansion of $1/n$ we do a series of calculations:

$10*r_{i - 1} = n*q_i + r_i; 0\le r_i < n$

we start with:

$1 = 0*n + 1; q_0 = 0; r_0 = 1$

The final decimal expansion is $q_0.q_1q_2q_3....$.

A few things to note:

$10*r_{i - 1} = n*q_i + r_i; 0\le r_i < n; q_i, r_i \in \mathbb Z^+$

$r_{i-1} < n$ so $10*r_{i-1} < 10*n$ so $q_i < 10$ so this *does* give us decimal digits.  (Just in case you were worried.)

Second: as $n \not | 10^k$ for any $k$ this process will never terminate.  (If we ever get a remainder of 0, that would mean $n*10^{-k}$ divides evenly into 1 or, equivalently, $n | 10^k$.)

As $r_i < n$ there are only a finite number of values for $r_i$ so eventually the series of remainders will have a duplicate $r_j = r_k$ even though $j < k$.

But if $r_j = r_k$ then $10*r_j = 10*q_{j+1} + r_{j+1}$ will have the same solutions as $10*r_k = 10*q_{k+1} + r_{k+1}$.  Hence $q_{j+1} = q_{k+1}$, and inductively, there will come a point where the decimal repeats infinitely.

Finally note.  given $q_l$ and $r_l$ we can determine $n*q_l + r_l = 10*r_{l - 1}$ so we can determine the values of the remainders *back* to the first equation.  That means the infinitely repeating sequence of decimals begins at the very begining, $q_1$.

So $h(n) = 0$.

(Note: For $m/n; m \ne 1$ the first equation is $m = q_1*n + r_1$ which is a different start.  Eventually the remainders, and thus the decimal digits, will repeat infinitely, but when we calculate back we *won't* go back to the very beginning.  So $m/n$ [$n$ not divisible by 2 or 5] can very well have a non-repeating decimal part although $1/n$ can not.)

Case 2:

$n = 2^j5^k$ then $h(n) = \max(j,k)$.

Pf:  Let $l = \max(j,k)$.  $2^j5^k | 10^l$.  ($n = $ either $2^{j-k}10^k;l =j$ or $n = 5^{k-j}10^j;l = j$.)

Let $10^l = m*n$.  ($m = 2^{l - j}5^{l-m}$ which is $2^{k-j}$ if $l = k$ or $5{j-k}$ if $l = j$.)

So $1/n = m/10^l$.  As with any integer, if $m = a_1a_2...a_s$ and $a_s \ne 0;s < l$,  $m/10^l = 0.(000...)a_1a_2....a_s$. which has $l$ digits before it terminates.

So $h(2^j5^k) = \max(j,k)$.

Comment: A simpler way to express it is to write $n=2^a5^bq$ where $q$ has no factors of $2,5$. The length of the non periodic part is $\max(a,b)$

Comment: I thought of that, but then I realised that was $n = 10^{\min(a,b)}2or5^{max - min}q$.  It's easier to express.  But harder to explain why.